# Opportunity.IsWon isn't won in test context

Tags: apex

I have a code in an Opportunity trigger that makes some updates when the Opportunity is won:

```
if (opp.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId 
    && opp.IsWon) {   
    //do stuff...
```

which works fine in the UI, but in a test context, even though the Opportunity stage name is correct, the IsWon flag doesn't get set. It isn't even in the object. When I debug the whole object, if I save the Opportunity from the UI I get

```
, RecordTypeId=012i0000000xnjhAAA
, StageName=Closed Won
, IsDeleted=false 
, IsClosed=true
, IsWon=true
```

but when run from a test context,

```
, RecordTypeId=012i0000000xnjhAAA
, StageName=Closed Won
```

and `IsDeleted`, `IsClosed` and `IsWon` don't appear in the object so they're effectively null.

I don't want to hardcode stagenames because that's evil. Has anyone managed to work around this without putting some `if Test.isRunningTest()` in the code? Because I don't like this either.

Comment: Is the test using the runAs method? where you specify the profile of the user who will run the test

Comment: Nope, it's just running as default / person-who-pressed-the-run-test-button

Comment: Are you re-querying the object after you've updated the StageName to Closed Won?

Comment: @AlexTennant No I'm not. Not in UI context or in test context. Do you think that could make a difference? I have had some test issues in the past where I had to requery a newly inserted object to get its ID to populate in test, when it was populated without requerying in normal use.

Comment: The field accessibility for the fields IsDeleted, IsClosed, IsWon might be hidden to the system administrator profile. If you go to Setup-Field Accessibility and then try and sort by field, what sort of permission does the system admin have on those fields?

Comment: @MihaiNeagoe They are system fields that don't have profile based accessibility. And anyway it's the same profile System Administrator doing both thing.

Comment: Are you able to post any more of your code? Are you testing your trigger by actually performing an insert or are you doing DML-less tests of a trigger handler class or similar?

Comment: The trigger handler is being tested by being triggered after an update dml

Comment: I  am not sure I can set isWon to run the handler without DML but I'm going to try that now.

Comment: @AlexTennant "interestingly" the code and test work fine in another org, and only fail having been ported to a package org for packaging. Opportunity.IsWon isn't writeable. I'm going to try putting an isRunningTest... workaround in.

Comment: you only can debug IsDeleted, IsClosed and IsWon  fields  in a after trigger. because they are system read only fields and they are setting after the before trigger. ¿Are you sure that you are debuging only in the after trigger?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be abandoned. You answered your own question but have not accepted either posted answer, and have not participated on SFSE in over a year.

Comment: FYI I'm seeing this issue as well within an Opportunity After-Record context within Flow automation, where `IsWon` will be `false`, even though the Opportunity has `StageName` = "Closed Won"

Answer (score 1):

You can create Opportunity objects with isWon set to true without having to go through DML to set the stageName to something that maps to 'won' as defined by the point-and-click set up. Here's how:

```
Opportunity o = (Opportunity) Json.deserialize('{"name":"foo", "isWon": true}',
                                                Opportunity.class);
```

The `JSON.deserialize` approach is a great way to set system fields for testmethods that want to verify sobjects and can avoid test record(s) setup via DML

Comment: Nice idea. I'll look into it.

Comment: cool - I also think that `Test.loadData()` will also do what you need

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by testing the trigger handler method directly rather than from DML. To do this I had to set the Opportunity to a ClosedWon stage, update it, and then query it back out of the database to get a correctly set IsWon flag.

Then I could pass the trigger handler method lists and maps of the object I just requeried and a new very similar object I made up that wasn't Won, so the method had the two to compare as if they were the "before changes" and "after changes" version of the same object.

This was an annoying introduction to world of DML-less testing, because I really want the Opportunity IsWon flag to be set the same in UI based save and trigger context save. And indeed it was when the code was in a sandbox. It only started to fail when the code was ported to a packaging org and added to a managed package.